# RFC_READ_TABLE does not return any records. Why?

Tags: vba, abap, saprfc, bapi

I am trying to get data from SAP for analysis using RFC_READ_TABLE. It returns `Fields` correctly. However, when trying to get the rows it returns zero rows.

```
  theFunc = functionCtrl.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE") '  
    Dim returnFunc As Boolean
    Dim returnParam As Object
    Dim retTab As Object
     theFunc.exports("query_table") = "MSKA"
    theFunc.exports("DELIMITER") = ";"
    theFunc.exports("NO_DATA") = "TRUE"
    theFunc.exports("ROWCOUNT") = "50"

    returnFunc = theFunc.call

     retTab = theFunc.tables("DATA")
```

msgbox retTab.rows.count  ' >>>>>> returns 0

Last step returns zero as records count. The table contains data.When I search for table FIELDS , it returns the table fields correclty.
Is this related to security issues?

Regards, 
Waleed

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting any data returned because you're populating the `NO_DATA` parameter (which should be a single character anyway, not `TRUE`, for example). You're also not providing a `WHERE` clause (in the `OPTIONS` table parameter).

From the function module definition:

[image: RFC_READ_TABLE]

If you provide `NO_DATA` with a value of a single space (or omit it, as a single space is the default value) as well as a valid `WHERE` clause in `OPTIONS`, you should get data returned.

Comment: I have already tried to set the NO_DATA parameter to " " or "TRUE" or "FALSE". All do not get records.

Comment: I also changed the table name to MARA , which is for material description which should have data. But no records are retrieved.

        theFunc = functionCtrl.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE")
        Dim returnFunc As Boolean
        Dim returnParam As Object
        Dim retTab As Object
        theFunc.exports("query_table") = "MARA"  
        theFunc.exports("DELIMITER") = ";"
        theFunc.exports("NO_DATA") = " "
        theFunc.exports("ROWCOUNT") = 50
         
        returnFunc = theFunc.call       
        retTab = theFunc.tables("DATA")
   
      msgbox  retTab.rows.count

Comment: I just noticed you're also not providing a value in `OPTIONS` - I've expanded my answer to include that

Comment: Is it mandatory to mandatory to add options ? Also, what is the nice tools your use to list function module. is it web tool ?

Comment: what if I want to list all records simply of the table. shall I add "*" into the options parameter ?

Comment: That screenshot is from transaction `SE37` in the SAP system. No, you need to provide a proper `WHERE` clause - `WHERE MATNR = '1234567'` etc. If you want a range of materials, then adjust accordingly.

Comment: how to add this option. It is not a exportation parameter. It is a TABLE. how to update my code to include the options ?   Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to refer to it as you do any other tables (using the `tables` property of `theFunc`).

Comment: I have tried , but I am not sure if I am doing it in the right way

Comment: theFunc.tables("options").rows.add(Nothing)

                               theFunc.tables("options").rows(1)(1) = "WHERE MATNR = 'N999'"
         retTab = theFunc.tables("DATA")
 
        returnFunc = theFunc.call

Comment: theFunc.tables("options").rows.add(Nothing)

Comment: theFunc.tables("options").rows(1)(1) = "WHERE MATNR = 'N999'"

Comment: retTab = theFunc.tables("DATA")

Comment: returnFunc = theFunc.call

Comment: MsgBox("rows found  " & retTab.rows.count)

Comment: Read the "Short Text" next to the NO_DATA parameter - Basically, anything other than a space " " will return no data.  Don't put "TRUE" or "FALSE", put " ".  And in normal (stupid) SAP convention, put "X" if you don't want data.

Comment: But I have alrady set it to space :  theFunc.exports("NO_DATA") = " "  .. and still no data